# rbenv build failed on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ruby, ubuntu, rbenv

I've successfully installed rbenv (along with the build tools) on my Ubuntu 14.04 desktop, and that appears to be working fine, but as soon as I try to install ruby 2.1.1, the build fails:

```
daniel@grape:~$ rbenv install 2.1.1
Downloading yaml-0.1.6.tar.gz...
-> http://dqw8nmjcqpjn7.cloudfront.net/5fe00cda18ca5daeb43762b80c38e06e
Installing yaml-0.1.6...
Installed yaml-0.1.6 to /home/daniel/.rbenv/versions/2.1.1

Downloading ruby-2.1.1.tar.gz...
-> http://dqw8nmjcqpjn7.cloudfront.net/e57fdbb8ed56e70c43f39c79da1654b2
Installing ruby-2.1.1...

BUILD FAILED

Inspect or clean up the working tree at /tmp/ruby-build.20140418142258.3543
Results logged to /tmp/ruby-build.20140418142258.3543.log

Last 10 log lines:
installing default ripper libraries
compiling ossl_pkcs7.c
compiling ossl_ssl.c
installing default openssl libraries
linking shared-object openssl.so
make[2]: Leaving directory `/tmp/ruby-build.20140418142258.3543/ruby-2.1.1/ext/openssl'
linking shared-object ripper.so
make[2]: Leaving directory `/tmp/ruby-build.20140418142258.3543/ruby-2.1.1/ext/ripper'
make[1]: Leaving directory `/tmp/ruby-build.20140418142258.3543/ruby-2.1.1'
make: *** [build-ext] Error 2
```

The contents of the log file can be found here: http://pastebin.com/SXxTeCJY

I've done some searching for help with this issue, including following what is said here: https://github.com/sstephenson/ruby-build/wiki - but I've not had any joy.

Comment: Did you run `apt-get install autoconf bison build-essential libssl-dev libyaml-dev libreadline6 libreadline6-dev zlib1g zlib1g-dev`?

Comment: Yes I did - but the solution posted below fixed it for me :)

Answer (score 39, accepted):

**UPDATE**: Use Ruby 2.1.2, it fixes this issue.

---

14.04 is probably shipping with readline 6.3, which uses `rl_hook_func_t` instead of `Function`.

This bug has already been reported and fixed in Ruby (https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/9578), but not released yet.

Until Ruby 2.1.2 comes out (which I assume will contain this fix), you can use a [patch](https://gist.github.com/mislav/a18b9d7f0dc5b9efc162) to properly support the new `rl_hook_func_t` method. Use this to install Ruby 2.1.1:

```
curl -fsSL https://gist.github.com/mislav/a18b9d7f0dc5b9efc162.txt | rbenv install --patch 2.1.1
```

(Source: http://gorails.com/setup/ubuntu/14.04)

Comment: Thank you very much, was struggling with this for quite some time now!

Comment: If I run that command using a chef LWRP execute I get "rbenv: not found". If I log in and run it directly it works. How can I use rbenv_ruby to build this?

Comment: @markhorrocks - you would need support added to the LWRP before you can patch Ruby. There seems to be pulls and forks supporting the various rbenv cookbooks but not seen a fix in the master branch yet. I use riotgames/rbenv-cookbook and [have got 2.1.1 installed from this fork of it.](https://github.com/fourseven/rbenv-cookbook).

Comment: how can I use that fork with Berkshelf?

Comment: Using fork in Bershelf sounds like a new question :-) However, good news, the fork is now into the riot games master branch. See answer below.

Comment: [Ruby 2.1.2](https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/downloads/) is out and resolves the issue.

Answer (score 4):

**UPDATE**: Ruby 2.1.2, fixes this issue. If you need to patch ruby with Chef for another reason follow the example here.

---

### Chef installation of Ruby 2.1.1 on to Ubuntu 14.04 using [LWRP](http://docs.opscode.com/lwrp.html)

Code to patch Ruby 2.1.1 on Trusty Ubuntu (14.04) using [Riotgames rbenv cookbook](https://github.com/RiotGames/rbenv-cookbook) - cut and pasted - no warranty :-) [I have a wrapper cookbook which is tested on Ubuntu 14.04 (release 1.0.4)](https://github.com/BCS-io/bcs_rbenv). Easiest way is get this going is to clone the repository and converge it on test kitchen. The main gotcha is that the cookbook uses Berkshelf 3.1.1 and most people are probably on 2 still. The pasted code should work on Berkshelf 2.x and 3.1.1.

*Berksfile*

```
cookbook 'rbenv', github: "RiotGames/rbenv-cookbook"
```

*Metadata*

```
depends 'rbenv'
```

*Attributes (attributes/default.rb)*

```
default['ruby']['version'] = '2.1.1'
```

*Recipe (recipes/default.rb)*

```
# patchutils is required to patch Ruby version
package 'patchutils'

include_recipe "rbenv::default"
include_recipe "rbenv::ruby_build"

# Installs a patched, global, ruby 
rbenv_ruby node['ruby']['version'] do
  global true
  patch "https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/projects/ruby-trunk/repository/revisions/45225/diff?format=diff"
end
```

[Discussion for patch](https://github.com/RiotGames/rbenv-cookbook/pull/97)

Rich