# rbenv build failed on Ubuntu 14.04. Must use ruby 2.0.0-p451

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ubuntu, version, rbenv

I am attempting to build a project in Ruby using rbenv, but get a build error when I run:

```
rbenv install 2.0.0-p451
```

I get a build error:

```
BUILD FAILED (Ubuntu 14.04 using ruby-build 20141208)

Inspect or clean up the working tree at /tmp/ruby-build.20141209122131.15088
Results logged to /tmp/ruby-build.20141209122131.15088.log
```

According to this post ([rbenv build failed on Ubuntu 14.04](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23155289/rbenv-build-failed-on-ubuntu-14-04)), this is a problem with Ubuntu 14.4, which ships with readline 6.3, and uses rl_hook_func_t instead of Function. I don't really know what this means, but unfortunately the solution in this post is to simply use Ruby 2.1.1. I cannot use another version of Ruby for this project, so I need a solution that will work in this version of Ruby and Ubuntu.

Side note, I am currently using RVM. It works, but I am having issues that I had hoped would be solved by using rbenv.

Answer (score 1):

Following the answer here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/23155490/254936

If you look at the comment at the bottom of the linked gist here:

https://gist.github.com/mislav/a18b9d7f0dc5b9efc162

Someone notes that they created a patch for Ruby 2.0.0-p451, here:

https://gist.github.com/riocampos/b2669b26016207224f06

I recommend trying that one, with the same patch instructions in the SO answer linked above.

Comment: So basically something like:

    [curl -fsSL https://gist.github.com/riocampos/b2669b26016207224f06 | rbenv install --patch 2.0.0-p415]

??

Comment: That's what I'd try. If you noticed, somebody says it works for other patch level versions of 2.0.0, too (though it sounds like you're pinned to p451).

Comment: Okay so this did not work. It did say:

"patching file ext/readline/extconf.rb
patching file ext/readline/readline.c"

while it was building, but eventually gave the same error. The script I ultimately ran was this:

"sudo curl -fsSL https://gist.githubusercontent.com/riocampos/b2669b26016207224f06/raw | rbenv install --patch 2.0.0-p451"

Comment: Lol. It worked, but it didn't solve the problem I was having with RVM :(